# Derivation of the conditional median for linear regression in “The elements of statistical learning ”

Tags: regression, machine-learning

My question is about "The elements of statistical learning" book. I would like to know how to prove that the use of the $L_1$ loss $$L_1: E\bigg[|Y-f(X)|\bigg]$$ leads to have conditional median $\hat{f}(x)=median(Y|X=x)$ as solution to the $EPF(f)$ criterion minimisation in eq(2.11): $$EPF(f)= E_X\bigg[E_{Y|X}\big[(Y-f(X))^2|X\big]\bigg]$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I think you misspelled something in the question. In your case it should be
$$
EPE(f)=\mathbb{E}(\vert Y-f(X)\vert).
$$
What you want to show is that
$$
\text{argmin}_{f \text{ measurable}}EPE(f)=\left(X\mapsto\text{median}(Y\vert X)\right)
$$
This is in fact equivalent to showing that the median is the best constant approximation in the $L^1$-norm, i.e. that

$$
\text{argmin}_{c}\mathbb{E}(\vert X-c\vert) = c^*
$$
where
$$
c^*=\inf\{t:F_X(t)\geq 0.5\}
$$
is the median of $X$ defined via the generalized inverse of the cdf $F_X(\cdot)$ of $X$.This can be easily shown as follows: First assume that $c>c^*$, then

\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\vert X-c\vert)&=\mathbb{E}((X-c)\chi_{\{X>c\}})-\mathbb{E}((X-c)\chi_{\{X\in(c^*,c]\}})-\mathbb{E}((X-c)\chi_{\{X\leq c^*\}})\\
&=\mathbb{E}((X-c^*)\chi_{\{X>c\}})-(c-c^*)\mathbb{P}(X>c)\\
&\quad\quad + \mathbb{E}((X-c^*)\chi_{\{X\in(c^*,c]\}})-2\mathbb{E}(X\chi_{\{X\in(c^*,c]\}})+(c+c^*)\mathbb{P}(X\in (c^*,c])\\
&\quad\quad-\mathbb{E}((X-c^*)\chi_{\{X\leq c^*\}})+(c-c^*)\mathbb{P}(X\leq c^*)
\end{align}
Now we bound
$$
-2\mathbb{E}(X\chi_{\{X\in (c^*,c]\}})\geq -2c\mathbb{P}(X\in (c^*,c]).
$$
Hence, we get
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(\vert X-c\vert)&\geq \mathbb{E}(\vert X-c^*\vert)+(c-c^*)\left(\mathbb{P}(X\leq c^*)-P(X>c)-\mathbb{P}(X\in (c^*,c])\right)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(\vert X-c^*\vert)+(c-c^*)(2\mathbb{P}(X\leq c^*)-1)\\
&\geq \mathbb{E}(\vert X-c^*\vert),
\end{align}
where we used that $c>c^*$ and $2\mathbb{P}(x\leq c^*)\geq 1$ by the definition of $c^*$. Analogously it can be shown that the same thing holds for $c<c^*$. Hence, we can conclude that the median is in fact the constant RV that approximates $X$ the best in $L^1$.

Finally this can be used to show the final result:

\begin{align}
EPE(f)&=\mathbb{E}(\vert Y-f(X)\vert)\\
&=\mathbb{E}(\mathbb{E}(\vert Y-f(X)\vert\vert X))\\
&\geq \mathbb{E}(\vert Y-\text{median}(Y\vert X)\vert\vert X)\\
&=EPE(\text{median}(Y\vert X))
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**INTUITION**
This part is taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/113336/167257).

Assume that $S$ is a finite set, with say $k$ elements. Line them up in order, as $s_1<s_2<\cdots <s_k$.

If $k$ is even there are (depending on the exact definition of median) many medians. $|x-s_i|$ is the **distance** between $x$ and $s_i$, so we are trying to minimize the sum of the distances. For example, we have $k$ people who live at various points on the $x$-axis. We want to find the point(s) $x$ such that the sum of the travel distances of the $k$ people to $x$ is a minimum.

Imagine that the $s_i$ are points on the $x$-axis. For clarity, take $k=7$. Start from well to the left of all the $s_i$, and take a tiny step, say of length $\epsilon$, to the right. Then you have gotten $\epsilon$ closer to every one of the $s_i$, so the sum of the distances has decreased by $7\epsilon$.

Keep taking tiny steps to the right, each time getting a decrease of $7\epsilon$. This continues until you hit $s_1$. If you now take a tiny step to the right, then your distance from $s_1$ increases by $\epsilon$, and your distance from each of the remaining $s_i$  decreases by $\epsilon$. So there is a decrease of $6\epsilon$, and an increase of $\epsilon$, for a net decrease of $5\epsilon$ in the sum.

This continues until you hit $s_2$. Now, when you take a tiny step to the right, your distance from each of $s_1$ and $s_2$ increases by $\epsilon$, and your distance from each of the five others decreases by $\epsilon$, for a net decrease of $3\epsilon$.

This continues until you hit $s_3$. The next tiny step gives an increase of $3\epsilon$, and a decrease of $4\epsilon$, for a net decrease of $\epsilon$.

This continues until you hit $s_4$. The next little step brings a total increase of $4\epsilon$, and a total decrease of $3\epsilon$, for an *increase* of $\epsilon$. Things get even worse when you travel further to the right. So the minimum sum of distances is reached at $s_4$, the median.

The situation is quite similar if $k$ is even, say $k=6$. As you travel to the right, there is a net decrease at every step, until you hit $s_3$. When you are between $s_3$ and $s_4$, a tiny step of $\epsilon$ increases your distance from each of $s_1$, $s_2$, and $s_3$ by $\epsilon$. But it decreases your distance from each of the three others, for no net gain. Thus any $x$ in the interval from  $s_3$ to $s_4$, including the endpoints, minimizes the sum of the distances. In the even case, Some people prefer to say that **any** point between the two "middle" points is **a** median. So the conclusion is that the points that minimize the sum are the medians. Other people prefer to define **the** median in the even case to be the average of the two "middle" points. Then the median does minimize the sum of the distances, but some other points also do.

**IN FORMULAS**
This is taken from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2364943/167257)

Consider two $x_i$'s $x_1$ and $x_2$,

For $x_1\leq a\leq x_2$, $\sum_{i=1}^{2}|x_i-a|=|x_1-a|+|x_2-a|=a-x_1+x_2-a=x_2-x_1$

For $a\lt x_1$, $\sum_{i=1}^{2}|x_i-a|=x_1-a+x_2-a=x_1+x_2-2a\gt x_1+x_2-2x_1=x_2-x_1$

For $a\gt x_2$,$\sum_{i=1}^{2}|x_i-a|=-x_1+a-x_2+a=-x_1-x_2+2a\gt -x_1-x_2+2x_2=x_2 - x_1$

$\implies$for any two $x_i$'s the sum of the absolute values of the deviations is minimum when $x_1\leq a\leq x_2$ or $a\in[x_1,x_2]$.

**When $n$ is odd,**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=|x_1-a|+|x_2-a|+\cdots+\left|x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}}-a\right| + \left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a\right|+\left|x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}-a|+\cdots+|x_{n-1}-a\right|+|x_n-a|
$$
consider the intervals $[x_1,x_n], [x_2,x_{n-1}], [x_3,x_{n-2}], \ldots, \left[x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}}, x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}\right]$. If $a$ is a member of all these intervals. i.e, $\left[x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}\right],$

using the above theorem, we can say that all the terms in the sum except $\left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a\right|$ are minimized. So
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=(x_n-x_1)+(x_{n-1}-x_2)+(x_{n-2}-x_3)+\cdots + \left(x_{\tfrac{n+3}{2}}-x_{\tfrac{n-1}{2}}\right) + \left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a\right| = \left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a \right|+\text{costant}
$$

To minimize also the term $\left|x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}-a \right|$ it is clear we have to choose $a=x_{\tfrac{n+1}{2}}$ to get $0$ but this is the definition of the median.

$\implies$ When $n$ is odd,the median minimizes the sum of absolute values of the deviations.

**When $n$ is even,**
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=|x_1-a|+|x_2-a|+\cdots+|x_{\tfrac{n}{2}}-a|+|x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}-a|+\cdots+|x_{n-1}-a|+|x_n-a|\\
$$
If $a$ is a member of all the intervals $[x_1,x_n], [x_2,x_{n-1}], [x_3,x_{n-2}], \ldots, \left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}\right]$, i.e, $a\in\left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}\right]$,

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-a|=(x_n-x_1)+(x_{n-1}-x_2)+(x_{n-2}-x_3)+\cdots + \left(x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}-x_{\tfrac{n}{2}}\right)
$$

$\implies$ When $n$ is even, any number in the interval $[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}]$, i.e, including the median, minimizes the sum of absolute values of the deviations. For example consider the series:$2, 4, 5, 10$, median, $M=4.5$.

$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-M|=2.5+0.5+0.5+5.5=9
$$
If you take any other value in the interval $\left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2} + 1} \right] =[4,5]$, say $4.1$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-4.1|=2.1+0.1+0.9+5.9=9
$$

Taking for example $4$ or $5$ yields the same result:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-4|=2+0+1+6=9
$$

$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-5|=3+1+0+5=9
$$

This is because when summing the distance from $a$ to the two middle points, you end up with the distance between them: $a-x_{\tfrac{n}{2}}+(x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}-a) = x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}-x_{\tfrac{n}{2}}$

For any value outside the interval $\left[x_{\tfrac{n}{2}},x_{\tfrac{n}{2}+1}\right]=[4,5]$, say $5.2$
$$
\sum_{i=1}^4|x_i-5.2|=3.2+1.2+0.2+4.8=9.4
$$

The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/113270/167257) has other good answers but in my opinion these are the clearest.

Comment: Why the downvote? Please explain so that I can correct my answer or remove it if totally wrong. Downvoting like this is meaningless

Answer (score -1):

Let's call $(Y - f(X))^2 = g(Y)$. Then, we know that, for continuous cases (for example) 
$$ E[g(Y)] =  \int g(y) f_Y(y) dy $$

And we also know that $$ P(A, B) = P(A|B) P(B)$$  or, 
$$ f_{y, x}(y, x) = f_{y | x}(y | x)  f_{x}(x) $$

Then, to derive $E_X \Big [ E_{Y|X} [g(Y) | X ] \Big ]$, we can do:

$$E_x \Big [ E_{Y|X} [g(Y) | X] \Big ] = 
E_x \Big [ \int_{Y} g(y) f_{y | x}(y | x) dy  \Big] \\
\int_{X} \Big[ \int_{Y} g(y) f_{y | x}(y | x) dy  \Big] f_{x}(x) dx
 $$

Which is:

$$ \int_{X}  \int_{Y} g(y) f_{y | x}(y | x)  f_{x}(x) dy dx $$
$$ \int_{X}  \int_{Y} g(y) f_{y, x}(y, x) dy dx $$

$$ \int_{Y}  g(y) \int_{X}  f_{y, x}(y, x) dy dx $$

$$ \int_{Y}  g(y) f_{y}(y) dy $$

that is the expectation of our $g(Y)$.

Comment: This does not answer the question.